# I'm making a game and this error shows up = ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python

```py
class Cuatro_en_linea():
    def __init__(self):
        

         self.tablero =  np.zeros((6,7)).astype(int)
        

    def colocar_fichas(self):
        self.columna = int(input("seleccione una columna del 0 al 6: "))
        while True:
            if self.columna < 0 or self.columna > 6:
                print("deben ser digitos del 0 al 6")
                self.columna = int(input("seleccione una columna del 0 al 6: "))
                
            else:
                self.tablero[5,int(self.columna)] == 0
                self.tablero[5,int(self.columna)] = 1
                print(self.tablero)
                    
                if self.tablero != 0:
                    self.tablero[4,int(self.columna)] = 1
                    print(self.tablero)
                
                elif self.tablero != 0:
                    self.tablero[3,int(self.columna)] = 1
                    print(self.tablero)
                    
                
                elif self.tablero != 0:
                    self.tablero[2,int(self.columna)] = 1
                    print(self.tablero)
                
                elif self.tablero != 0:
                    self.tablero[1,int(self.columna)] = 1
                    print(self.tablero)
                
                elif self.tablero != 0:
                    self.tablero[0,int(self.columna)] = 1
                    print(self.tablero)
                    
                else:
                    self.columna_llena = "la columna esta llena, seleccione otra:" 
                    self.columna
```

I'm trying to make  a game called four in a line, and I want to make a condition that if the user chooses a full column, then must choose another, but
when I put `if self.tablero != 0`, the error shows up.

"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

How can I solve it?

Comment: `self.tablero` is a grid of numbers, not a single number. What do you expect `self.tablero != 0` to give you?

Comment: as `self.tablero` is a 2D arra, the condition like `self.tablero != 0` is not possible because it contains multiple True or False. Maybe you wanted to specify a particular index in the 2D array like `self.tablero[0,1] != 0`for instance

Comment: also every condition in the if elif is identical `self.tablero != 0` which is obviously a mistake

Comment: what do you want to check with `self.tablero != 0` ? Variable has many values - and if you want all values `!= 0` then you may need `all( self.tablero != 0 )`. And if you need at least one value `!= 0` then you may need `any( self.tablero != 0 )`

Comment: to check column you should use `all( self.tablero[:, self.columna] != 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

First:  to check column you need

```
self.tablero[:, self.columna] != 0
```

But `numpy array` gives result as list `[True, False, ...]` (with result for every cell separatelly) but `if` needs single `True` or `False` so you should use `all()`

```
if all(self.tablero[:, self.columna] != 0):
```

---

**EDIT:**

When I look at your code then I think you want to check every cell separatelly

```
if self.tablero[4, self.columna] != 0:

    # ...

elif self.tablero[3, self.columna] != 0:

    # ...

elif self.tablero[2, self.columna] != 0:

    # ...
```

Comment: yes, if I do what you did, can I solve it?

Comment: @tobias first try, next ask. I don't have all your code and I can't test it. You may have other problems which I can't see. But for this part of code I would do what I show in answer.